# Does inception model label multiple object in one image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition

I  used `retrain.py` to train tensorflow with my own dataset of traffic sign but it seems it doesn't capture multi-object in one image.I am using the `label_image.py` to detect the object in my image. I have an image of two road sign which exists in my dataset but i get only one sign with high accuracy. It doesn't detect other sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood what a classification CNN does. Inception is built and trained to classify an image. Not objects in an image. For this reason you will only get a single result from `label_image.py` as it is using softmax to generate a confidence that an image is of a certain class.

It does not identify individual objects as I explained to you on another question here: [Save Image of Detected object from image using Tensor-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942587/)

If you are trying to detect multiple signs then you will need to use object detection models.

Comment: Yes i got,I found YOLO which is doing the classification+localization is the right approach for my case?

Comment: Yeah Yolo is pretty good. If you want to run it on Tensorflow then you'll need to run it with Darkflow. You can retrain with your annotated data. You'll need to provide bounding boxes.